# Instruments 9.2 font size

Tags: xcode-instruments

**Is there a way to increase the size of the 4 point font used in instruments 9?**

[image]

Comment: I don't know, but you can use System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom to compensate. You could also, of course, set your display scaling to show less info at larger sizes, generally.

Comment: @ken-thomases Yeah, i guess accessibility zoom will have to work.  Thanks.